# Get Processor.Name from an object

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get processor information, specially name like **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz**.

Searching web I found a function which gives me all the properties of processor using a `for-each` loop.

Below is full function and a sample link is also attached. I am trying to get only name property. How do I get `name property` without for-each loop or in other method so that I can get processor name only. I will use this code to collect ***Hard Disk, RAM, Processor*** information but not all information only name, size, etc.

[Sample File Download Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHrgZqX_QluRbhpXtY9j6fwH_K-Y4Gr1/view?usp=sharing)

```
Public oWMISrvEx As Object 'SWbemServicesEx
Public oWMIObjSet As Object 'SWbemServicesObjectSet
Public oWMIObjEx As Object 'SWbemObjectEx
Public oWMIProp As Object 'SWbemProperty
Public sWQL As String 'WQL Statement
Public n


Sub ProcessorWMI()
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processor")

sWQL = "Select * From Win32_Processor"
Set oWMISrvEx = GetObject("winmgmts:root/CIMV2")
Set oWMIObjSet = oWMISrvEx.ExecQuery(sWQL)
intRow = 2
strRow = Str(intRow)

sht.Range("A1").Value = "Name"
sht.Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True

sht.Range("B1").Value = "Value"
sht.Cells(1, 2).Font.Bold = True

For Each oWMIObjEx In oWMIObjSet
    For Each oWMIProp In oWMIObjEx.Properties_
        If Not IsNull(oWMIProp.Value) Then

            If IsArray(oWMIProp.Value) Then
                For n = LBound(oWMIProp.Value) To UBound(oWMIProp.Value)
                    Debug.Print oWMIProp.Name & "(" & n & ")", oWMIProp.Value(n)
                      sht.Range("A" & Trim(strRow)).Value = oWMIProp.Name
                        sht.Range("B" & Trim(strRow)).Value = oWMIProp.Value(n)
                        sht.Range("B" & Trim(strRow)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                       intRow = intRow + 1
                    strRow = Str(intRow)
                Next

            Else
                sht.Range("A" & Trim(strRow)).Value = oWMIProp.Name
                sht.Range("B" & Trim(strRow)).Value = oWMIProp.Value
                        sht.Range("B" & Trim(strRow)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                intRow = intRow + 1
                strRow = Str(intRow)
            End If

        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to get the name of the processor

```
Sub ProcessorName()
    Dim objPross As Object, cpu As Object

    Set objPross = GetObject("WinMgmts:").instancesof("Win32_Processor")

    For Each cpu In objPross
        Debug.Print cpu.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run the code I get `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz`.

> This will serve my purpose. Anyway is there any list of property of
>   object cpu in your code like name? – Harun24HR 14 secs ago

You can read the name directly from the registry then?

```
Sub ProcessorName()
    Dim objWsScript As Object

    Set objWsScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Debug.Print objWsScript.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0\ProcessorNameString")
End Sub
```

Comment: This will serve my purpose. Anyway is there any list of property of object `cpu` in your code like `name`?